# After using Template (jsf) in my xhtml, the commandLink and CommandButton tags are not invoking any action

Tags: java, html, jsf, templates, jsf-2

I have used JSF templating in the following manner:

TemplateHeader.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
</h:head>
     <h:body>

            <ui:composition>
                    <div></div>   
             </ui:composition>

      </h:body>
</html>
```

TemplateMenu.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
</h:head>
        <h:body>
            <ui:composition>
                <div></div>
            </ui:composition>
        </h:body>
</html>
```

TemplateContent.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition>
          <div></div>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

TemplateFooter.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition>
        <div></div>  
    </ui:composition> 
</h:body>
</html>
```

Then i have included all of this in a complete template file:

CompleteTemplate.xhtml

```
 <html> // with all the necessary tags as above
  <h:head>
    <title>State Transport Department- Work Schedule</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/templateCSS.css"/>
 </h:head>

 <h:body style="with the reqd styles">

 <div style="css styles">

  <div style="">
 <ui:insert name="header">
                <ui:include src="/webpages/templates/TemplateHeader.xhtml"/>
            </ui:insert>

</div>

<div>
 <ui:insert name="menu">
                <ui:include src="/webpages/templates/TemplateMenu.xhtml"/>
            </ui:insert> 
</div>

<div>
  <ui:insert name="content">
                <ui:include src="/webpages/templates/TemplateContent.xhtml"/>
            </ui:insert>
</div>

<div>
 <ui:insert name="footer">
                <ui:include src="/webpages/templates/TemplateFooter.xhtml"/>
            </ui:insert> 
</div>

 </div>

 </h:body>
 </html>
```

Then i included this page into my main pages for example:

Test.xhtml

```
 <html>
 <h:body>
    <h:form>
<ui:composition template="/webpages/templates/CompleteTemplate.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="menu">
      //override the previos wid menues etc
            </ui:define>

             <ui:define name="content"> 
 <h:commandLink id="allocateButton" value="Test Submit"
 action="#{myTaskBean.viewMyTask}"/> 

 <h:commandButton id="allocateButton" value="Test Submit"
 action="#{empDutySchedBean.testMethod}"/>
              </ui:define>

 </ui:composition>
         </h:form>
      </h:body>
   </html>
```

All the commandLinks and commandButttons were not working. Normal html anchor used for menu worked.

For CommandLink I got error as:

> This link is disabled as it is not nested within a JSF form.

for CommandButton: the button's name in the source code doesn't render to the inbuild jsf one like *j_something* and it doesn't invoke the java method.

Some people have said that it is the problem with the way I have done templating. However I feel that it is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing your templating the wrong way, you don't need to set `<h:body>` and `<h:head>` in all your pages.

Your complete structure should look something like:

`mainTemplate.xhtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<f:view>
     <h:head>
         <ui:insert name="header">
                 <!-- so that each implementing page can set its own title -->
             <title></title>
         </ui:insert>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
         <!-- if your menu is shared through all site, otherwise set it as ui:insert -->
         <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
         <ui:insert name="body"></ui:insert>
         <ui:insert name="footer"></ui:insert>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

Now your form page would be:

`test.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                template="mainTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="header">
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:form id="myForm">
            <!-- your jsf inputs, commandbutton, etc... -->
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="footer">
        <!-- include can come anywhere inside ui:define -->
        <ui:include src="testPageCustomFooter.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

You can of course have multiple templates, but your `<ui:composition>` can implement one at a time via `template` attribute.
Implementing a template doesn't force you to `ui:define` all `ui:insert`, it's up to your need in each particular page.
Also notice in `test.xhtml` that you don't re-write `<html>`, `<h:head>` or `<h:body>`, you start your implementation directly inside `<ui:composition>`, and anything outside `<ui:define>` won't be rendered in your page.
Hopefully this would clear things out.

Comment: you have explained really well! I understood where I have made the mistake. Thank You soo much! Just one more thing; where should i apply the css properties? And if i have certain Links that are common on all the pages do i add them to the **mainTemplate** page or individually to all?

Comment: and add jQuery external Link reference ?

Comment: I tried implementing it, but it didnt work properly. What i did was i created an xhtml file, with all the components common to all the pages called **Components.xhtml** , then i **<ui:include src=""/>** it to my **MainTemplate.xhtml** page. In **MainTemplate.xhtml** I added a **insert** element which i would override in my other pages. After including it to my **Test.xhtml** page, the **menu** etc i added in Components page didnt appear, but some css properties worked. And i tried to <define> the portion, but it didnt appear on the screen. I dont kw why.

Comment: i have added my new query as another question, you might understand my problem there well.       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008471/template-jsf-is-not-working-properly-when-i-override-the-elements-they-dont       Sorry for all the trouble i must be causing! :)

Comment: @user3485692 If you have a shared links you set them in your `mainTemplate.xhtml`, that includes script sources, and css links.
Regarding your structure seems fine, but i'm not so sure of how your `ui:define` is set. Always view source to check what is rendered and what's not

Comment: i viewed source and saw that only the css properties have applied to div tag. the rest of the contents is not showing

Answer (score 1):

JSF ignores everything outside `ui:composition`. If you use templates, the component tree is built based on the content of the template (and there I see no `h:form`). JSF only uses the parts inside `ui:define` from the page using the template.

So your `h:form` is not added to the component tree. You would have to add it to the template or inside a `ui:define`.