# Template (jsf) is not working properly. When i override the elements, they dont appear on the page.

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2

I have done template in 3 steps:

Firstly i created a xhtml file with content that is common to all the pages:

```
AllComponentsTemplate.xhtml


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<head>
    <title>State Transport Department- Work Schedule</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/CompleteTemplateCSS.css"/>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/templateCSS.css"/>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="menu">
<h:outputLabel  class="welcomeNote" value="#{welcomeBean.fullname}" />

         <ul class="ulForMyAccount"><li> <h:outputLabel value="My Account" id="mainAnchor"/>

                            <ul ><li> <a href="/webpages/ChangePasswordxhtml.xhtml"    id="subAnchor"  >Change my Password</a>  </li> </ul></li></ul> </div>

<div class="contentBody">

            <div class="menuTable">
                        <table class="templateBody" >
                            <tr>
                                <td class="navigationLink" > <ul><li>
                                            <h:link  value="Home" outcome="/webpages/NewWelcome.xhtml"  rendered="#{welcomeBean.home}" class="mainLinks"/> 
                                        </li></ul> </td>

                            </tr>  </table>   </div>   </div>

   <div class="footer"></div>

    </div>  </body> </html>
```

Then i created a **MainTemplate.xhtml** page which i would be using in other pages as templates:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<f:view>

    <h:head>
        <title>State Transport Department-Work Schedule</title>                
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

         <ui:include src="AllComponentsTemplate.xhtml"/>
         <ui:insert name="informationBody"></ui:insert>

     </h:body> </f:view> </html>
```

Then i added this template to my first page **Trial.xhtml**

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                 xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                 template="/webpages/templates/CompleteTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="informationBody">
        <h:form>
              <h:commandButton id="allocateButton" value="Test Submit" action="#{empDutySchedBean.testMethod}"/>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

**Note**: trial.xhtml **doesn't** have a **html, head, body** tag.

**Problem**: till the MainTemplate.xhtml page, all the components including the link etc were perfectly visible. **However** after including the template into Trial.xhtml page, The **My Account**, **Welcome** label, **Home** naviagation link didn't appear.

Apart from this, all the css i applied for the webpage's background color appeared.

I dont know why. Help would be dearly appreciated. I am a beginner at coding.

**Thank You! :)**

Comment: I've updated my answer, with a suggestion of re-structuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `AllComponentsTemplate.xhtml` as `ui:composition` as well it doesn't need `html`, `head` and `body`, and as `AllComponentsTemplate.xhtml` will be included, it doesn't need to add `template` attribute, or `define` sections.

If i were you I would set `AllComponentsTemplate.xhtml` as the main template it self with `html`, `h:head` and `h:body`, etc.., and let `Trial.xhtml` implement it.
Later on if you needed another pages to have a shared view, you go ahead and create `AnotherComponentsTemplate.xhtml` and let them implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link it will help you as you are begineer.

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/

and considering your problem use h:head and h:body for all html tags as Najjar metioned in his answer.